# Bug in Chrome 73 and 74? It doesn't show inspected element info

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm wondering if it's a bug, but in previous versions of Chrome, when you right-click over an element and select `inspect`, it shows the element marked with a rectangle and some info about it. Now I'm trying to do it, and it works the first time, but not the second. For example, the first time (with the developer tools closed):

[image]

Works.

But if I select another element with the developer tools already open:

[image]

That rectangle with info about the selected element doesn't appear despite the element appears selected in the HTML code (to the right).

Is this a bug? Does it happens only to me?

**EDIT:** I tested it in Chrome 72 today and yes, it works differently (marking the element no matter if the developer tools are already open, so I think it's a bug).

**EDIT II**: It happens in Chrome 74 too. I just tested it.

Comment: Does it work in Chrome 75?

Comment: @JoshLee I didn't try it.